# Install for All Users with ClickOnce deployment

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

I am trying to create a deployment package that will install my vb 2013 application for all users of the client computer.  How can I do this?  Is there a manifest entry I can add or change?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the "InstallAllUsers" property of your deployment project to true or false as needed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5f981xa1(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I am not seeing the InstallAllUsers property anywhere in the properties.Where would this property be found?

Comment: If you right click the deployment project in Solution Explorer and select "Properties" menu item, it should display.

Comment: I do not have a deployment project, I am just using the publishing wizard within visual studio for a click once app.  Is this the wrong approach?  I am fairly new to the .net development and deployment.  In vb 6.0 the deployment and packaging wizard handled all.  Is this not the case with .net?

Comment: ClickOnce deploys applications inside a user's home folder to avoid permissions problems if installing in %programfiles%, so it's only available for current user. If you need to install it for all users, you need to create a deployment project instead of using ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: Figured that out as I am researching.  Do you know how to get the templates for deployment packages populated in the New Project dialog?  The only setup and deployment project I have is an InstallShield Limited Edition Project that I installed.  I do not see the default options described in 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

although I see now that that pertains to .net 2.0 are the obsolete at this time?

Comment: It seems they removed the basic deployment project from vs2013, and it takes a separate install:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3041773-bring-back-the-basic-setup-and-deployment-project

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx

Comment: This is not a solution for ClickOnce projects; at least not anymore.